# T-SQL how to add sequence number for groups, duplicate values in special column should have same order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My data in table:

```
id    gname1    gname2    date1    order1
1                         data 1     1
5      red                data 5     2
4     blue                data 4     3
6     blue                data 6     4
3     blue      color1    data 3     5
8     blue      color2    data 8     8
2      red                data 2     6
7                         data 7     7
```

I need to get a new numbering column (order2) in my query,
should order by the existing "order1" column, 
and if "gname1 is not null" and "gname1 and gname2 are both same", we should use the same value(first one in group), so #5=#2=2 and #4=#6=3.

what I want:

```
id    gname1    gname2    date1    order1   order2
1                         data 1     1        1
5      red                data 5     2        2
4     blue                data 4     3        3
6     blue                data 6     4        3
3     blue      color1    data 3     5        4
2      red                data 2     6        2
7                         data 7     7        5
8     blue      color2    data 8     8        6
```

DB: sql server 2008

Thanks.

Comment: look at `ID 1 and 7`. Isn't it that the value of order2 is 1?

Comment: @JW - "`gname1` is not null" is one of the conditions for matching, and I assume the empty values are meant to be interpreted as `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to rework your schema as that seems a bit unpleasant to me.

However if you really want to do this then the following query will work:

```
;WITH cte([id],[gname1],[gname2],[date1],[order1])
AS
(
            SELECT 1 [id],  NULL [gname1],  NULL [gname2],  'data 1' [date1],   1 [order1]
UNION ALL   SELECT 5,       'red',          NULL,           'data 5',           2
UNION ALL   SELECT 4,       'blue',         NULL,           'data 4',           3
UNION ALL   SELECT 6,       'blue',         NULL,           'data 6',           4
UNION ALL   SELECT 3,       'blue',         'color1',       'data 3',           5
UNION ALL   SELECT 8,       'blue',         'color2',       'data 8',           8
UNION ALL   SELECT 2,       'red',          NULL,           'data 2',           6
UNION ALL   SELECT 7,       NULL,           NULL,           'data 7',           7
)

SELECT
     [id]
    ,[gname1]
    ,[gname2]
    ,[date1]
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [order1]) [order1]
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
             x.[id]
            ,x.[gname1]
            ,x.[gname2]
            ,x.[date1]
            ,MIN(ISNULL(y.order1, x.order1)) [order1]
        FROM 
            cte x
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            cte y
            ON
            x.gname1 IS NOT NULL 
            AND
            x.gname1 = y.gname1
            AND
            ISNULL(x.gname2, '') = ISNULL(y.gname2, '')
        GROUP BY
            x.[id],x.[gname1],x.[gname2],x.[date1]
    ) z
```

Comment: It works. It's really not a good schema, I'm going to change it first. Thank you!